# Need for Three.js canvas to take all the width of a jQuery modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, three.js

I have an issue about the space of a THREE.js canvas that I have put into a jQuery modal window.

I did a first version of my code with THREE.js canvas taking all full window (no div used, only into body). Here's a capture of this version seen in the browser window :

[image: THREE.js canvas taking full browser window]

Now, I would like to put all this canvas into a jQuery modal window. Here's a capture of what I get (with also Firefox inspector) :

[image: THREE.js canvas not taking full modal window]

As you can see on this second version, **the displayed canvas is not integrated into all the modal window width** and I don't understand why (the blue area corresponds to the THREE.js canvas). This canvas is created with the following code :

```
  // Main container
  var popID = 'mainWindow';
  mainContainer = document.getElementById(popID);
  // Initiate WebGLRenderer renderer
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
  // Width and Height
  popWidth = $('#' + popID).data('width'); // Get width
  popHeight = $('#' + popID).data('height'); // Get width
  renderer.setSize(popWidth, popHeight);
  renderer.sortObjects = true;
  // Append to mainContainer
  mainContainer.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

It seems that menu (DatGUI) on the right **prevents canvas to take all the width of modal window**.

The DOM structure of modal window is created with :

```
<div id="mainWindow" data-width="900" data-height="490" class="center popup_block" style="display: block; width: 1296px; height: 705.6px; top: -93.3px; left: 62px;"><a href="#" class="close"><img src="./close_pop.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close"></a>
    <div id="global-ui">
    <div id="buttons-wrapper">
    <div id="buttons"><button id="startButtonId" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" tabindex="13">Start</button><button id="resetButtonId" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" tabindex="14"></button><button type="submit" id="saveButtonId" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"></button>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dg main a" style="-moz-user-select: none; width: 350px;">
    ...
```

You can directly test the second version on the following link :

[testing version][3]

**You have to click a first time on the image once you are on the page and, then, you make sphere appearing by clicking on start button at the bottom right of modal window, just below of the right menu** : sphere is appearing on Firefox, Opera but it is badly placed on Chrome.

If someone could help me to get a THREE.js canvas which fills all width of modal window, this would be fine.

Regards.

Comment: I dont use three so cant answer definitively, and your example just bogs my machine down (its a good spec machine) so I am guessing that you just need to set the canvas element `rendener.domElement.className = "canvasStyle";` and create a style that positions the canvas absolutely with the top left at 0px this will prevent the other DOM elements interfering with its layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to run on my machine so this is how I fixed it.

Create new style for the canvas

```
.canvasElementClassName {
   position : absolute;
   top : 0px;
   left : 0px;
 }
```

Then for the code you just need to ensure that the canvas element has the correct style.

```
renderer.domElement.className = "canvasElementClassName";
```

I think your problem can also be solved if you give the DataGUI and floating container (position : absolute or relative) as now you are sharing the canvas container with the dataGUI elements causing the canvas to be sized to accommodate.

You can do that with (I think or similar)

```
    // you need an element that has style
    // position : relative;
    // top : 0px;
    // right : 0px;
    // get that element
    var container = document.getElementById("GUIcontainer");
    // create the GUI with autoplace turned off
    var GUI = new dat.GUI({ autoPlace: false });
    // add the GUI to the container
    container.appendChild(gui.domElement);
```